# ssh authentication output meaning: type 1

Tags: ssh

I try to connect with ssh to a remote server using a private key and I see as part of the output:

```
debug1: identity file /home/gigi/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
```

What does `type 1` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (open)ssh client has a list of several [key types](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/e2cb445d786f7572da2af93e3433308eaed1093a/sshkey.h#L56):

```
/* Key types */
enum sshkey_types {
    KEY_RSA,
    KEY_DSA,
    KEY_ECDSA,
    KEY_ED25519,
    KEY_RSA_CERT,
    KEY_DSA_CERT,
    KEY_ECDSA_CERT,
    KEY_ED25519_CERT,
    KEY_XMSS,
    KEY_XMSS_CERT,
    KEY_UNSPEC
};
```

These types are referred to in the [sshkey.c code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/c7670b091a7174760d619ef6738b4f26b2093301/sshkey.c#L86) when setting up the `keytypes` structure; they are the `type` value in that structure. To get the corresponding name, take the key type from the above sequence use its value (starting from 1) and find the corresponding `name` or `shortname`. Interpolating them by hand (and sorting by `type`) gives the following table of key names, shortnames, and types:

```
NULL, NULL, -1
rsa-sha2-256, RSA, 1
rsa-sha2-512, RSA, 1
ssh-rsa, RSA, 1
ssh-dss, DSA, 2
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256, ECDSA, 3
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384, ECDSA, 3
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521, ECDSA, 3
ssh-ed25519, ED25519, 4
rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com, RSA-CERT, 5
rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com, RSA-CERT, 5
ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com, RSA-CERT, 5
ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com, DSA-CERT, 6
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com, ECDSA-CERT, 7
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com, ECDSA-CERT, 7
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com, ECDSA-CERT, 7
ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, ED25519-CERT, 8
ssh-xmss@openssh.com, XMSS, 9
ssh-xmss-cert-v01@openssh.com, XMSS-CERT, 10
```